# Unable to run Cloud Build Local after installing it via gcloud CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I want to run Google Cloud Build locally. Based on their docs, I installed it using:

`gcloud components install cloud-build-local`

Got a success message and reinstalling says the component is up-to-date.

However, when I try invoking `cloud-build-local --help`, per their docs, I get this error: `command not found: cloud-build-local` with both Bash and Zsh.

I've tried `source ~/.bashrc` and `source ~/.zshrc` and `gcloud cloud-build-local --help` (maybe namespace was the issue) to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround - See GitHub issue and in it is a helpful Gist as well:

[GitHub Issues Link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-build-local/issues/112)

Since I used Homebrew to install Google Cloud SDK on MacOS, I found the binary for the cloud components here: `/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin`. In the parent directory, you should find two sets of `.inc` files for both Bash and Zsh for auto-completion and updating your PATH.

Comment: It looks like Google has officially retired the official Cloud Build Local project. I'm adding my community fork here that has a few added features already: [github.com/chriseaton/cloud-build-local](https://github.com/chriseaton/cloud-build-local)

Answer (score 0):

Since google officially retired the original tool - I created [a fork](https://github.com/chriseaton/cloud-build-local) which added some very much needed features, should someone in the future find this.